# Get highest value in multi multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

i need to get the the max or highest value in a multi dimensional array.

here is my array `$array`:

```
[pay] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 'hi'
                )
            [payment] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 35
                    [currency] => USD
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 'lol'
                )
            [payment] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 50
                    [currency] => USD
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 'ok'
                )
            [payment] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 30
                    [currency] => USD
                )
        )
)
```

i need to get the max value for `amount` which is 50. how can i do that?

here is what i tried but it did not work:

```
$max = -9999999; //will hold max val
$found_item = null; //will hold item with max val;

foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{
    if($v['Total']>$max)
    {
        $max = $v['Total'];
        $found_item = $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why are you using the form `[pay] => Array` instead of normal `'pay' => Array` PHP form? Is this a new PHP feature? Or just your pseudo-code? Thanks.

Comment: @aendeerei  This is just how print_r() displays to the screen.  There is no problem with the OP's array structure.  See my answer for a usable php array variable.

Answer (score 4):

Simple as this one-liner.  Get the `payment` column data, then pull the `amount` data from that generated array, then get the max value.  Done and done.  (Sorry it took me so long -- I had to convert your posted array to a usable php array.)

Input:

```
$array=["pay" => [
            ["title"=>["name"=>'hi'],"payment"=>["amount"=>35,"currency"=>"USD"]],
            ["title"=>["name"=>'lol'],"payment"=>["amount"=>50,"currency"=>"USD"]],
            ["title"=>["name"=>'ok'],"payment"=>["amount"=>30,"currency"=>"USD"]]
    ]
];
```

Method #1 ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6588651025f88aada931b1c0fde9a46b4700164f)):

```
echo max(array_column(array_column($array["pay"],"payment"),"amount"));
```

Method #2 ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7337aab76b8b6b23de6277d6e0d748c428f7db80)):

```
$max=0;
foreach($array["pay"] as $subarray){
    if($max<$subarray["payment"]["amount"]){
        $max=$subarray["payment"]["amount"];
    }
}
echo $max;
```

Method #3 ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1261c3004b86bf8d31c8368734fb78d63b0d6d64)):

```
$payments=array_column($array["pay"],"payment"); // declare payments array
rsort($payments);                                // sort by amount DESC
echo $payments[0]["amount"];                     // access the first amount value
```

Output:

```
50
```

The benefits to method #1 are: code brevity, no condition statements, no global variable declarations/overwriting, just straight to the max value.  What's not to love!

If method #1 is too scary, you can go with my method #2 (which was first posted by aendeerei).  I don't prefer it because it requires the extra steps of initializing the $max variable, performing a conditional check on each iteration, and overwriting the `$max` variable when appropriate.  Actual performance on the foreach loop is going to depend on the size of your array, but the difference between the two methods is going to be unnoticable to humans.

Method 3 might be my new favorite because there are no conditionals and just two functions before it is accessed purely by keys.  However, it does require the declaration of a partial copy of the input array which must be sorted.  Anyhow, take your pick -- it's all the same outcome.

Comment: @JohnJaoill  This will outperform Sahil's answer because there is no need to sort and then re-index the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope this will be helpful. Here we are just using simple `foreach` to get it done.

**Solution 1:**

[**try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/798780)

```
$max=0;
foreach($yourArray["pay"] as $value)
{
    if($max<$value["payment"]["amount"])
    {
        $max=$value["payment"]["amount"];
    }
}
echo $max;
```

**Solution 2:**

Just for testing purpose i have converted you `array` to `json`. Here we are using `array_column` two times to get the columns

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/798746)

```
$internals=array_column($yourArray["pay"],"payment");//retrieving payments
$amounts=array_column($internals, "amount");//retrieving amounts
arsort($amounts);
print_r(array_values($amounts)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use Usort and get the 1st index

```
$arr= array
(
     array
        (
            'payment' => array
                (
                    'amount' => 35,
                    'currency' => 'USD'
                )
        ),

     array
        (
            'payment' => array
                (
                    'amount' => 50,
                    'currency' => 'USD'
                )
        ),
     array
        (
            'payment' => array
                (
                    'amount' => 80,
                    'currency' => 'USD'
                )
        )
);

function sortAmount($x, $y) {
    return $y['payment']['amount'] - $x['payment']['amount'];
}

usort($arr, 'sortAmount');
echo "<pre>";
$highest=$arr[0];
print_r($highest)
//for value only
$highest=$arr[0]['payment']['amount'];
```

Working fiddle
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p5hw-ivei

Comment: for value only: `$highest=$arr[0]['payment']['amount'];`

Comment: @mickmackusa: Thanks , I updated my answer

Comment: I think this is a clever approach, but you have to modify the OP's input array to make it work.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/80086accb7b9f4b17e8853c31c998df617f87b19

Answer (score 1):

```
$max = 0;
foreach ($array['pay'] as $key => $item) {
    $amount = $item['payment']['amount'];
    if ($amount > $max) {
        $max = $amount;
    }
}
echo $max;
```

Comment: if you aren't going to use `$key`, you can omit it from the foreach()

Comment: @mickmackusa Good point! I knew it, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Shorthand:

```
$result = array_reduce($array['pay'], function($a, $b){
  return $a ? ($a['payment']['amount'] > $b['payment']['amount'] ? $a : $b) : $b;
});

var_dump($result['payment']['amount']);
```

Comment: I like this method and I don't.  I don't normally gravitate to `array_reduce()` but it seems to do the trick for this question.  I'm not sure how much I like the nested ternary operators though.  A great demonstration of its capacity anyhow.

Comment: The condition logic can be consolidate to `array_reduce($array['pay'], fn($a, $b) => $a && $a['payment']['amount'] > $b['payment']['amount'] ? $a : $b)`

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example with an array named pay. You can adapt this method for your own array. This code will work for an array of n elements. Here I consider 3 as the number of elements in the array named $pay.  You can replace the max elements in the array in the place of 3 for controlling the loop control variable 'i'.

```
$big=$pay[0];
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){
 if($pay[i]>$big)
     $big=$pay[i];
}
echo $big;
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. Ask for any clarification.

Comment: "pay" is not the array, it is the first key's name in `$array`.  You really should be using a `count()` instead of a hardcoded 3.